# Variable before or after value in IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

Is there a difference between these two statements:

`if ($a == 'hello') { ... }`

and

`if ('hello' == $a) { ... }`

I've noticed applications like Wordpress tend to use the latter, whereas I usually use the former.

I seem to remember reading something a while ago giving justification for the latter, but I can't recall the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference. It is used so that an error is thrown in case you accidentally make an assignment instead of a comparison:

```
if('hello' = $a)
```

`if($a = 'hello')` would assign to the variable and not throw an error.

It might also be used to explicitly show that **if** you have an assignment in an `if` statement, you really want to have it there and it is not a mistake (consistency).

Comment: This pretty much sums it up, though I'd just like to mention that while using this style may prevent errors, it does make the if-clauses harder to read sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. By the way, I hate that "unnatural" style.

Answer (score 2):

The justifikation for the latter is that if you mistakenly type `=` instead of `==` (assignment instead of comparision) you'll get compiler error (can't assign to constant).